# Android ViewModel call Activity methods

Tags: android, android-activity, mvvm, listener, viewmodel

I'm using android AAC library and Android databinding library in my project. I have AuthActivity and AuthViewModel extends android's ViewModel class. In some cases i need to ask for Activity to call some methods for ViewModel. 
For example when user click on Google Auth or Facebook Auth button, which initialized in Activity class (because to initialize GoogleApiClient i need Activity context which i can not pass to ViewModel, view model can not store Activity fields). 
All logic with Google Api and Facebook API implemented in Activity class:

```
//google api initialization
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

//facebook login button
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
```

Also i need to call sign in intent which requires Activity context too:

```
Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_AUTH);
```

I can not request facebook login and google login, or startActivity intent from view model class, so i created class interface AuthActivityListener:

```
public interface AuthActivityListener {
    void requestSignedIn();

    void requestGoogleAuth();

    void requestFacebookAuth();

    void requestShowDialogFragment(int type);
}
```

Implement listener in activity class:

```
AuthActivityRequester authRequestListener = new AuthActivityRequester() {
        @Override
        public void requestSignedIn() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AuthActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            AuthActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void requestGoogleAuth() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_AUTH);
        }
        ...
```

And assign this listener in view model class to call activity methods:

```
// in constructor
this.authRequester = listener;

// call activity method
public void onClickedAuthGoogle() {
        authRequester.requestGoogleAuth();
}
```

After google or facebook authentication passed i call view model method from activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_AUTH) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
                if (acct != null) {
                    viewModel.onGoogleUserLoaded(acct.getEmail(), acct.getId());
                } else {
                    viewModel.onGoogleUserLoaded("", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain me is this approach of communication between view model and activity is right, or i need to find another way to call activity methods from view model ?

Comment: Hey did you find the proper MVVM structure for the Google and Facebook Sign In?I am Looking for the same.

Comment: Facing the same issue.. would like to learn how you solved it..

Comment: Did anyone find another solution for this, where we don't have to pass a reference from View to ViewModel?

Comment: If anyone comes across, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275216/10939976).

Comment: I think it is okay to make an exception and have activity handle the flow if external APIs are designed that way. The goal should be to implement a solution, that adheres to the framework component lifecycle and initializes/terminates objects and services in a graceful manner without leaking resources. MVVM is one way to do it, but your own solution might just work as well.

Answer (score 8):

There are several different approaches on how to do this.
Here I want to share my approach with you. Which, in my opinion, is the most suitable for MVVM pattern ideology.

As was mentioned - "*View Model must know nothing about the View and reference it*". This leaves not many options on how a View Model will call an Activity method. First, what comes to mind is a *Listener* approach. But this approach has several drawbacks in my opinion:

- The `View` should take care of subscribing/unsubscribing to/from `ViewModel`, as it's lifetime most likely shorter than `ViewModel`'s
- The first drawback also leads to a situation where something happened and the `ViewModel` should call `View`'s method but the `View` is in between subscribing/unsubscribing; `ViewModel` also should aware of empty listener situation as it can be `null`
- When adding new methods of *ViewModel-Activity* communication you will have to make changes in `ViewModel`, `Activity` and `Listener` interface.

So the *Listener* approach doesn't suite quite well. And it looks more like an MVP approach. To eliminate the above-mentioned drawbacks (or at least some of them), I've created, what I call, **ViewModel Events** approach. In this approach, `ViewModel` "emits" (or generates) it's events and lets the `View` to observe them. Let me show what I'm talking about.

At first, we will need some representation of the `ViewModel` event.

```
abstract class ViewModelEvent {
    var handled: Boolean = false
        private set

    open fun handle(activity: BaseActivity) {
        handled = true
    }
}
```

As you already can see, the `handle()` method will do the magic. When the `Activity` will handle received event it will pass its instance to `handle()` method as a parameter. Inside this method, we can call any `Activity` methods (or safe cast it to some specific `Activity`). The `handled` property is aimed to not let the `Activity` to handle this `ViewModelEvent` twice.

Further, we need to create some mechanism for the `ViewModel` to emit its events. `LiveData` suits the most for these needs. It will cancel an observer subscription on lifecycle events and it will store last emitted event (that is why the `ViewModelEvent` should have the above-mentioned `handled` property).

```
abstract class BaseViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val observableEvents = MutableLiveData<ViewModelEvent>()

    fun observeViewModelEvents(): LiveData<ViewModelEvent> = observableEvents

    protected fun postViewModelEvent(event: ViewModelEvent) {
        observableEvents.postValue(event)
    }
}
```

Nothing complex here. Just a `MutableLiveData` (exposed as `LiveData`) and a method to emit events. By the way, inside the `postViewModelEvent` we can check the thread this method was called from and use `MutableLiveData.postValue` or `MutableLiveData.setValue`.

And finally, the `Activity` itself.

```
abstract class BaseActivity: Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        viewModel.observeViewModelEvents().observe(this, Observer {
            val event = it.takeUnless { it == null || it.handled } ?: return@Observer
            handleViewModelAction(event)
        })
    }

    protected open fun handleViewModelAction(event: ViewModelEvent) {
        event.handle(this)
    }
}
```

As you can see, general events can be handled in the `BaseActivity`, while some specific events can be handled by overriding the `handleViewModelAction` method.

This approach can be changed for specific needs. For example, `ViewModelEvent` doesn't have to work with `Activity` instance and can be used as a "marker" event or it can pass some specific parameters for the required action, etc.

The **ViewModel Events** approach makes *ViewModel-Activity* communication robust and seamless. `Activity` will have to subscribe once and it will not miss the latest `ViewModel`'s event.

Answer (score 5):

the most difficult part of MVVM is **View model must not know about view and reference them**

This is quite strong restriction.

You have some options about that

**1. View model methods receveing context argument**

You can make methods receveing context from view(this method is called from view).

After you can instantiate context related variables.

If you are aware about memory leak, just destroy it when view is pause or stop using Lifecycle aware AAC and reinstatiate when resume or start of Activity or Fragment.

About onActivityResult, I think your solution is not bad because API support is like that.

**2. get context from view with data binding**

in layout xml, you can send view itself with event listener.

```
<Button
    ....
    android:onClick=“@{(view) -> vm.onClickFacebookLogin(view)}”
```

Then you can receive view and retrieve context from view in Viewmodel

**3. Use AndroidViewModel**

AndroidViewModel class is same with ViewModel class without that has Application context.

You can use Application Context with

```
gerApplication()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

well your approach is quite good. But somehow your interface depends on the activity means if you are reusing your view these interface makes no use or may be for that scenario you have to create new interface to solve your problem.

But if you create an instance of Activity then you have control of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to call Activity's public method from viewModel.

1. By casting activity with context like

   MonthlyAttendance activity = (MonthlyAttendance) context;

   activity.getAttendance();

Here, Activity context is required in ViewModel. You can pass context in ViewModel with the help of ViewModelProvider.Factory.

2. With the help of MutableLiveData class and observers like

   MutableLiveData callMethod = new MutableLiveData<>();

   callMethod.setValue(true)

   viewModel.callMethod.observe(this, this::getAttendance);