# pass onActivityResult data to viewmodel while facebook login imports import android.content.Intent

Tags: android, mvvm, facebook-login, google-signin

I followed the answer in this link in order to do facebook and google login in mvvm pattern.

[Google/Facebook Sign In in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287013/google-facebook-sign-in-in-mvvm)

My login activity receives facebook and google login data

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        viewModel.onResultFromActivity(requestCode,resultCode,data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
```

LoginViewModel

```
fun onResultFromActivity(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
//callback manager for facebook login

        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when(requestCode) {
            GOOGLE_SIGN_IN -> {
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                handleSignInResult(task)
            }

        }
    }
```

In my viewmodel, I had to import  android.content.Intent to pass CallbackManager of facebook. Is it against mvvm architecture? What should i do in this case?

Comment: what do u want to do exactly.In the viewModel u cannot pass the activity as arguement/viewModel does not hold the reference of the activity it is a bad practice.

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J  i am not passing activity to viewmodel. I am passing data  which received from onActivityResult in activity to view model .

Comment: u get the viewmodel object from view modal provider then set the data to view mondel.In the viemodal class u can use livedata/mutable live for the data

Comment: In an Android context, if you're aiming to be able to Java Unit Test your `ViewModel` then you're going to have a hard time of it due to the Android component in there.

Comment: How would i avoid using Intent in  viewmodel in this case