# How to register StartActivityForResult event to ViewModel? [MVVM]

Tags: java, android, mvvm, google-signin

I have a problem implementing Google signin with MVVM in Java.
here, in a normal way you will see this sample code from Google:

**PROBLEM:**

in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Here is the Issue:
     * Google Object is defined in View - Activity
     * I would like to have Google Object defined in my ViewModel
     */
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

// when Google Button CLicked
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { signIn(); }

private void signIn() {
    /* Here is the Issue:
     * I have to get this process done in View Model
     * so view will not reference any Google Object
     */
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Below will be processed in ViewModel
    GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

**QUESTIONS:** *see comment

so I came out with Idea Below:

in Activity:

```
// when Google Button CLicked
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { viewModel.loginGoogle(); }

private void subscribeUi() {
    // register startActivityForResult Event to ViewModel and set this activity as receiver...
    // viewModel.startActivityForResultEvent.setEventReceiver(this Activity)
    // How to do this?
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // send the result to View Model
    viewModel.onResultFromActivity(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    // escallate to super
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

now in ViewModel:

```
public void viewModelOnCreate() {
    // This is what i want: Google object defined in View Model
    // but I dont know how to call startActivityForResult from here?
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplication(), gso);
}

// triggered when login button pressed
public void loginGoogle(){
    // send Trigger startActivityForResult(getGoogleSignInIntent(), GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) this event should be catch later in my Activity
    // How to do this?
    // maybe something like:
    // startActivityForResultEvent.sendEvent( ActivityNavigation.startActivityForResult startActivityForResult(getGoogleSignInIntent(), GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
}

public void onResultFromActivity(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // do whatever needed here after received result from Google
    // for example:
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

any Idea how to get this achieved?
been scratching my head to get this done...
thanks and Appreciate the help :)
}

Comment: you cannot pass activity context as parameter in `loginGoogle()`?

Comment: it can, but understanding from here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html that: `Caution: A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context.`

Comment: but you can just to encapsulate it inside method, not to store it as a class variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use SingleLiveData to open new screen. See: 
https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8

1. You create class with all necessary parameters to start activity
2. In ViewModel you create this class with parameters you need
3. You create single live data field in your ViewModel and observe it from activity/fragment
4. You send this class with SingleLiveData

create class:

```java
public Enum Screen {
   LOGIN
}
```

in ViewModel:

```java
...

private SingleLiveData<Screen> onOpenScreen = new SingleLiveData<Screen>()

public SingleLiveData<Screen> observeScreenOpen() {
    return onOpenScreen
}

public void loginGoogle(){
    onOpenScreen.value = Screen.LOGIN
}

...
```

in activity/fragment

```java
viewModel.observeScreenOpen(this, new Observer<Screen> {screen->
    if(screen == Screen.LOGIN) {
        //start your activity here
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but your link is on Kotlin, I need it on Java..
and second, I have SingleLiveData in Java, but I'm not sure how to implement it to my case - if you have any snippet code, I very much appreciated - Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 1 thing, I'm not quite sure with: `ClassWithYourParams` what's that? and how to implement that to my case?

Comment: parameters for extras of your activity. If they not exist you can create enum class ScreenEvent. Add there event START_ACTIVITY and send it in SingleLiveData

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry, I'm still figuring out that is ClassWithYourParams - I still dont get it work...

Comment: Thanks, but: `if(screen == Screen.LOGIN) {` throw error: `operator == cant be applied to lambda param` and second: `//start your activity here` i cant start the activity there because Google object is not in View Activity/Fragment

Comment: Use anonymous class instead of lambda. Use activity/fragment reference when start activity

Comment: Do you mean send activity/fragment reference to view model? that was @Pavel Poley initial suggestion in comment above -- anyway, I saw a good solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287013/google-facebook-sign-in-in-mvvm?noredirect=1&lq=1 but it's in kt I have difficulties to translate it to java (even with decompiler)

Comment: I mean you should observe activity start in your activity/fragment, send this event from ViewModel. Doesn’t keep android references in viewModel

Comment: Thank you Peter, that is what I actually asked in my initial question, Im not sure on how to observe (or register) the result of `StartActivityForResult` from my activity

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following, it is not hold global reference to `context` so it will not leak

```
  public void loginGoogle(Context context){

         if(isSigningIn)
            return

         context.startActivityForResult(getGoogleSignInIntent(), GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
         isSigningIn = true;
    }
```

Comment: if view model will contain code like this, this method (and logic) will not be testable with unit tests because you cannot mock context

Comment: Isn't https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/mock/MockContext for this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be disencourage by the documentation and function that replaced startActivityForResult:

> Register a request to start an activity for result, designated by the given contract. This creates a record in the registry associated with this caller, managing request code, as well as conversions to/from Intent under the hood. This *must* be called unconditionally, as part of initialization path, typically as a field initializer of an Activity or Fragment.
> If the host of this fragment is an ActivityResultRegistryOwner the ActivityResultRegistry of the host will be used. Otherwise, this will use the registry of the Fragment's Activity.

Attention for the "This must be called unconditionally, as part of initialization path".

Also notice this IlliegalStateException message:

> Fragment [this] is attempting to registerForActivityResult after being created. Fragments must call "registerForActivityResult() before they are created (i.e. initialization, "onAttach(), or onCreate()).

So my suggestion is to put the contract and `registerForActivityResult()` on your Activity or Fragment `onCreate` and whatever you will be doing with the result in a function in your view model / domain class, which is basically what you are already doing.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is register a callback in the ViewModel that is invoked that the Activity can react to. Then the ViewModel can own the bulk of the business logic but does not have to have a reference to the Activity or Context and the Activity can deal with the Activity-specific stuff of launching an Intent.

Example:

Callback Interface:

```
interface OnSignInStartedListener {
    void onSignInStarted(GoogleSignInClient client);
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel {
    private final OnSignInStartedListener mListener;

    public ViewModel(OnSignInStartedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void viewModelOnCreate() {
        // This is what i want: Google object defined in View Model
        // but I dont know how to call startActivityForResult from here?
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplication(), gso);
    }

    public void loginGoogle() {
        // Invoke callback here to notify Activity
        mListener.onSignInStarted(mGoogleSignInClient);
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mViewModel = new ViewModel(new OnSignInStartedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInStarted(GoogleSignInClient client) {
            startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    });
    ...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Invokes listener this activity created to start sign in flow
    viewModel.loginGoogle();
}
```

Hope that helps!